# How to fix Git input/output error while reading from pack file with invalid object?

Tags: git

Error reading from .git/objects/pack/pack-47a2235260b7047f83581ee204e35febfacc081c.pack: Input/output error and invalid object

I encountered the following error while working with Git(while committing changes):

error: error reading from .git/objects/pack/pack-47a2235260b7047f83581ee204e35febfacc081c.pack: Input/output error
error: error reading from .git/objects/pack/pack-47a2235260b7047f83581ee204e35febfacc081c.pack: Input/output error
error: invalid object 100644 66fb4a489015b948dd5c1c225396316128d96720 for 'source/database/factories/RoomMessageFactory.php'

I'm unsure about the cause of this error and how to resolve it. It seems to be related to reading from a pack file, but I'm not sure what the "Input/output error" indicates. Additionally, the error message mentions an "invalid object" for a specific file in my repository ('source/database/factories/RoomMessageFactory.php').

Can someone help me understand the root cause of this error and suggest a solution? How can I fix the input/output error and resolve the issue with the invalid object in Git?

Also when i run git repack following output occurs

[git repack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbB9z.png)

And also when i run git gc following output occurs

[git gc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IBA0.png)

Thank you in advance for any insights or assistance!

Comment: Please don't add images of text - it's much, much easier for the rest of us if you paste that output instead.

Answer (score 0):

The message "Input/output error" is associated with the C error code EIO.  Typically, that means that there's a problem with your disk or file system, and for whatever reason the data cannot be read or written properly.

This is not a normal error to have, and it may indicate serious data loss that's already occurred or that will occur if you don't do anything about it.

Similarly, signal 7 is SIGBUS on x86, which can occur if an I/O error occurs while using `mmap` to map a file, such as what Git does with pack files.

It looks like you're probably on Ubuntu, so I'd run `sudo dmesg | less` to look for any file system or disk errors.  If there's a file system error, you can reboot into single user mode and run `fsck` on the disk in question (which is probably the root partition, seen under `mount`), and if there's disk errors, you can look into installing `smartctl` and querying the status of the disk.  It may be that your disk actually needs replacing, depending on the `smartctl` output and the kernel messages.

Asking more about this is off-topic here, but would be appropriate on Super User, so you can ask about problems or error messages more in depth there.